# Ubuntu linux - new "MIDI" device diagnostic software?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, midi

I'm looking for software that will tell me if a particular USB device meets the MIDI standard.

I have a new Madcatz wireless USB controller, that I suspect will need a special driver before it's generally perceived as a MIDI controller. (I have a Novation controller that has a similar problem.)

In this case, I need to look at USB data to see what it's sending.  The keyboard has a separate 5-pin DIN port with actual MIDI, but I want the wireless dongle to send MIDI into my PCs USB port.

Here's what lsusb shows:

lsmod on ubuntu shows this:

```
snd_seq_midi            5829  0 
snd_rawmidi            23420  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event      7267  2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
```

root@sagan:/proc# lsusb

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:0084 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 1bad:3330 Harmonix Music
```

Comment: This is not a programming question so it's off-topic for SO.  It should be on [su]

Comment: No software needed.  Just find out if it is "class-compliant" or not.  If you would actually post the device you have, we could even Google it for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Using my M-audio O2 keyboard as a test, it seems that my devifce must not be "class compliant" when using the USB port.  Too bad, because the wireless USB dongle is a thing of beauty.  What good is a keytar that forces you to be tethered to a MIDI cable?

Comment: The device in question, BTW, is a Harmonix-labaled keytar (made by madcatz), bundled with Rock Band 3 software for the Wii.  It's the last device in the "lsusb" output.  The device has a MIDI port,but it doesn't speak proper MIDI over when sending data to the USB dongle.

Comment: Assuming the keyboard is only a HID device on USB, there is Windows and Mac software to perform HID to MIDI conversion.  I'm looking for Linux software that I can modify as needed (Open Source). http://www.steim.org/steim/junxion_v4.html